# Changing faces one at a time, outside customize

Tags: faces

Is there a way to change faces one at a time, outside of customize?

In my `custom-file` I see a big blob of face customizations that starts with:

```
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 ...
```

So I suppose `custom-set-faces` is not the right function to use for changing just one face, but I'm not sure what is.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `custom-set-faces` or `custom-theme-set-faces`, with a list of one face - no problem. Or you can use `modify-face`. Or, as @erikstokes mentions, you can use `set-face-attribute`.

Note that the Elisp manual, node [Attribute Functions](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html), says this about `set-face-attribute` (but it doesn't say why):

> This function is mostly intended for internal usage.

Note too that in the case of user options (variables), there are the single-option functions `customize-set-variable` and `customize-set-value`, which are companions to the multiple-option function `custom-set-variables` that is written to your `custom-file` (or init file).  They are also commands, letting you choose the option using completion.

But for faces there is no such single-face companion function (and no command, other than `customize-face`).

Comment: For some reason `custom-set-options` does not appear in my `custom-file` (nor in `C-h f custom-set-options`).  Instead, it uses `custom-set-variables`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant `custom-set-variables` - I updated the answer to correct that.

Answer (score 9):

[`set-face-attribute`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dattribute) is the function you want.  For example to make comments green and bold:

```
(set-face-attribute 'font-lock-comment-face nil
  :foreground "Green"
  :weight 'bold)
```

There are also helper functions [`set-face-foreground`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dforeground) and [`set-face-background`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dbackground) for the common case of just changing the color of the face.

All of them can be executed via `M-:`, in a scratch buffer ([`C-x C-e`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Lisp-Eval.html)), or put into `~/.emacs`. The last 2 can also be executed via `M-x`.

To display the list of colors use [`M-x list-colors-display`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Colors.html).

Comment: Also, the changes are applied immediately. Only the specified [attributes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Face-Attributes.html) are changed. And `nil` means for [existing and newly created frames](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Attribute-Functions.html#index-set_002dface_002dattribute).